# How I can change the default sylius bundle object?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

how i can change the next tag in `show.html.twig`

```
{{ form_row(form.quantity, {'attr': {'class': 'center-text'}, 'empty_value': '1'}) }}
```

I need change the style, how I do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `style` property to the `attr` with any CSS styles

```
{{ form_row(form.quantity, {'attr': {'class': 'center-text', style: "color: red;"}, 'empty_value': '1'}) }}
```